# How to automatically update SwiftUI View depending on an ObservableObject hidden as an Associated Value of an Enum Property?

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data, swiftui, enums

**Context**

I have an `Enum` where one of its `Cases` has an `ObservableObject` as an `Associated Value`. I also have a `SwiftUI View` with a `Property` of this `Enum`. This `View` displays `Data` of the associated `ObservableObject`, if applicable. However, since I can't define the `Enum` itself as an `ObservedObject`, the `UI` does not change when the associated `ObservableObject` changes.

---

**Code**

```swift
// This is actually a CoreData NSManagedObject.
class CustomComponent: ObservableObject { ... }

enum Component {
    case componentA
    case componentB
    case custom(_ customComponent: CustomComponent)

    static func getComponents(with customComponents: FetchedResults<CustomComponent>) -> [Component] {
        var components = [.componentA, .componentB]
        for customComponent in customComponents {
            components.append(.custom(customComponent))
        }
        return components
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .componentA: return "Component A"
            case .componentB: return "Component B"
            case .custom(let customComponent): return customComponent.name
        }
    }
}

struct ComponentsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)]) private var customComponents: FetchedResults<CustomComponent>

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Component.getComponents(with: customComponents)) { component in
            ComponentView(with: component)
        }
    }
}

struct ComponentView: View {
    // I can't define this as ObservedObject, however, this View should update when the associated ObservableObject updates.
    let component: Component

    var body: some View {
        Text(component.name)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal, that, even though the `ObservableObject` is hidden as an `Associated Value` of an `Enum`, the `ComponentView` updates when the `Associated Value` changes?

Comment: @NiravD Thank you for your answer. I actually have many more than two fixed `Components`. As far as I know, it is not possible to create `NSManagedObjects` temporary without a `Context`, therefore, adding those to a `List` is not working or am I getting something wrong?
I would like to prevent the need for saving those fixed `Components` inside `CoreData`, since it can cause so many problems, especially when you start supporting `iCloud Sync`.

Comment: One question does this all static components come before core data components, in that case you can add two ForEach in List. One for fixed components and another for core data components

Comment: @NiravD I could split it into two `ForEach`, however, without adding a second `ComponentView` (and many other Views, since many use `Component`), it will result in the same problem, since I am passing the `Enum Case`, not the `ObservableObject` itself.

Comment: @NiravD I am looking for a solution to implement default / fixed `Objects` without having to save them into `CoreData`, but while being able to share `Code` (e.g. `SwiftUI Views`) between them and their dynamic `NSManagedObject` counterparts. 
The reason why I don't want to populate `CoreData` with those default / fixed `Objects` is, that this is really prone to bugs, especially when working with `CloudKit`.

Comment: @NiravD my first idea was to generate `NSManagedObjects` temporarily without inserting them into a `Context`, however, this is not possible because because a `Context` is required. Using an `Enum` with an `Associated Type` was my second idea, which is working fine, except the missing `View` updates.
I am happy for any help on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. Even though it involves some duplicate `Code`, it is the best I was able to come up with.
If you know a better one, feel free to share it!

---

**Code**

```swift
struct ComponentView: View {
    let component: Component

    var body: some View {
        if case .custom(let customComponent) = component {
            CustomComponentView(customComponent: customComponent)
        } else {
            Text(component.name)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct CustomComponentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var customComponent: CustomComponent

    var body: some View {
        Text(customComponent.component.name)
    }
}
```